# How to stop sound from playing, or how do I make it play ONCE?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, frontend, html5-audio

I'm animating a chat, but I only want the notification sound to play ONCE -- only when the first grey chat appears (#msg4). However, if I click the button/input field again, it'll play again. How do I make it stop after that? I tried audio.pause, audio.load...I can't make it work.

This is how it works so far (click the input field to load messages): https://ixd1231.firebird.sheridanc.on.ca/narrative_sound/chat.html

HTML

```
<div class="messages" id="chat-window">
  <div class="blue invisible" id="msg1"> Hi! I'm looking for an old friend. She attended Martin Grove a few years ago.</div>
  <div class="blue invisible" id="msg2">Her name is Sam. *insert pic of Sam and MC*</div>
  <div class="blue invisible" id="msg3">Did you know her or her last name by any chance</div><div class="grey" id="msg4" style="display: none">Hello there!</div>
  <div class="grey" id="msg5" style="display: none">Unfortunately, I did not have the pleasure of teaching Sam. Her last name and whereabouts are a mystery to me as well.</div>
<div class="grey" id="msg6" style="display: none">
 However, I do know she was in the photography club. I always saw her carrying a camera, always taking pictures.
      </div>
 
</div>

<div class="input" id="chat-button" onClick="blueMessage()"></div>
```

JS

```
var audio = new Audio('Sound.mp3');


function blueMessage() {
    if (HTMLElementsArr.length > 0) {
        HTMLElementsArr.shift().classList.remove('invisible');

    }


    if (!HTMLElementsArr.length) {
        greyMessage();    
    }

}

function greyMessage() {
    setTimeout(show_msg4, 1500);

}

function show_msg4() {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(show_msg5, 1500);
    audio.play(); //SOUND PLAY

}

function show_msg5() {
    document.getElementById("msg5").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(show_msg6, 2500);
    msg5.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });

}

function show_msg6() {
    document.getElementById("msg6").style.display = "block";
    msg6.scrollIntoView({
        behavior: 'smooth'
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create global variable, change the value inside `show_msg4()`

```
var isPlayed = false;

function show_msg4() {
    document.getElementById("msg4").style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(show_msg5, 1500);
    if(!isPlayed){
        audio.play(); //SOUND PLAY
        isPlayed = true;
    }

}
```